# angular properties not synchronised with view

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am using angular 9.1.13 and ionic 6.13.1.

My use case is I want to navigate from my app to phone native settings and view the value of these settings in my app with a toggle button when I come back to my app.

When I come back in my app the value of my settings is not updated into the view. If I click on a element of the view, the value is updated. Same goes if I navigate back and forth into the view manually.

I tried back and forth navigation into the component, but I end up with navigation history duplicate.
I tried reloading the page with js but I lost track of the previous page visited.
I tried running the code updating my variable into a zone but I got the same result.

my page:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/services/auth.service';
import { OpenNativeSettings } from '@ionic-native/open-native-settings/ngx';
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { NotificationService } from '../../../services/notification.service';
import { OnesignalService } from '../../../services/onesignal.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-notifications',
  templateUrl: './notifications.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./notifications.page.scss'],
})
export class NotificationsPage implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup;
  prefs: any;
  isNotificationActivated: boolean;
  constructor(
    private onesignalService: OnesignalService,
    private notificationService: NotificationService,
    private router: Router,
    private platform: Platform,
    private openNativeSettings: OpenNativeSettings,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private auth: AuthService,
  ) {

    platform.resume.subscribe ( (e) => {
      this.notificationService.setIsNotificationActivated();
      onesignalService.setBackendNotificationStatus(this.isNotificationActivated);
    });
  }

ngOnInit() {
    this.notificationService.isNotificationActivated.subscribe( (status) => {
      this.isNotificationActivated = status;
    });
    this.auth.notificationPrefs()
      .subscribe((data) => {
        this.prefs = data;
        this.setPrefs();
        this.notificationService.setIsNotificationActivated();
      });
  }
...
}
```

my service:

```
import { Injectable, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Diagnostic } from '@ionic-native/diagnostic/ngx';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NotificationService {

    constructor( private diagnostic: Diagnostic){}

    @Output() isNotificationActivated = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

    setIsNotificationActivated(){
        this.diagnostic.isRemoteNotificationsEnabled().then((success) => {this.isNotificationActivated.emit(success); })
        .catch((err) => {console.log(err); });
      }

}
```

and my html:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-back-button text="" color="light"></ion-back-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>Notifications</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content class="ion-padding-top">
  <ion-card>
    <ion-item class="toggle">
      <ion-label class="ion-text-wrap">Autoriser les notifications</ion-label>
      <ion-toggle (click)="openNativeSetting()" [checked]='isNotificationActivated'></ion-toggle>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: you should use `platform.resume()` to update your values after updating them from native settings. 
Check: https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/platform#resume

Comment: this does not compile. An extract from the doc you sent:

```this.platform.resume.subscribe(async () => {
  alert('Resume event detected');
});
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: I do not see relevant errors, I just experience this strange behaviour. I think this bug report describe my problem:
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/18342

Comment: I have a bad idea to make it work :P trigger a click event on `platform.resume` manually :D

Comment: @Najam Us Saqib in fact I use a smiliar workaround, I reload the entire page but this is not elegant and cause other kinds of problems